# Depth peeling in mayavi

Tags: python, vtk, mayavi

I'm trying to use [depth peeling](https://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Depth_Peeling) in [Mayavi](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/), but I'm not suceeding. In principle I believe depth peeling should work in my system, since I tried the python sample at "[vtk depth peeling issue doing multiple renders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39138909/vtk-depth-peeling-issue-doing-multiple-renders)" and it not only shows a nice cylinder (though it also does without depth peeling), but `ren.GetLastRenderingUsedDepthPeeling()` ouputs `1` (and `0` without). This is what I've tried with Mayavi:

```
import numpy
import mayavi.mlab as mlab
x, y, z = numpy.ogrid[-5:5:20j, -5:5:20j, -5:5:20j]
scalars = x * x * 0.5 + y * y + z * z * 2.0
fig = mlab.figure()
mlab.clf()
if (True): # enable depth peeling
    renderer = fig.scene.renderer
    window = renderer.render_window
    window.alpha_bit_planes_on()
    window.multi_samples = 0
    renderer.use_depth_peeling = 1
    renderer.maximum_number_of_peels = 20
    renderer.occlusion_ratio = 0.002
obj = mlab.contour3d(scalars, contours=[20,50], transparent=True)
print obj.scene.renderer.use_depth_peeling
print obj.scene.renderer.last_rendering_used_depth_peeling
mlab.show()
```

But I only get `0` as the last output. Also, I see the common artifacts that I'm trying to solve precisely with depth peeling:

[image]

Left: correct render, the bottom green surface is visible through the top one.
Center: layer artifacts as the camera crosses the z=0 plane.
Right: wrong transparency, the top surface now completely occludes the bottom one.

I'm using the default Mayavi (4.4.3) and libVTK (6.2.0) on Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, if it's possible to fix this in Mayavi 4.4.3, but the newer version, Mayavi 
 4.6.2 (Python 3.6.6, vtk 8.1.1, Windows 10) does not produce either of those artefacts.

[image: mayavi 4.6.2]

It still prints `0` as the last output though.